# In after effects sort project layers by name (Numerical Order)

Tags: layers, adobe-after-effects

In after-effects to sort project layers by name, I click name toggle button in the project window

but I can't seem to sort them in numerical order - you know, 1,2...9,10,11...

Instead, it always sorts them according to text sorting : 10, 100, 101, 102...11, 111, 112, ....

How can I sort my column of numbers by number instead of by text?

[image]

Comment: What version is your After Effects? Mine works just fine, even with the S in front of the number. S1, S2, S10, S11, S21, S22, etc...

Comment: Its Adobe After Effects CC 2020

Comment: @renanAlmeida828 Might be an OS thing. Are you on Mac?

Comment: Oh... Yes, I'm on a MacOS Catalina. Totally forgot about this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found Solution, Just add 0 before single numeric value

Like 1, 2, 3 -> 01, 02, 03...

Let double numeric value be same 11, 12, 13...

End result - 01, 02... 09, 10, 11...

[image]

Comment: Not automatic, but a good Workaround! Up

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

1. Remove the S and see if that makes any differente (i.e. instead of **S10**, it becomes **10**)
2. Check your Adobe After Effects version, mine is **CC2020 V.17.0.0 Build 557** and it works just as expected, even with the S in front of the number
3. Try ordering your files through File Path column (make sure they are all in the same folder) and they will order by filename, numbers in ascending order *(AE2020 17.0.0 557)*

Comment: It doesn't help, it is still sorting in that manner.

Comment: Yout method only works if I remove everything before and after the number, which makes the layer name-less